# moment-timezone format es local, return "Fecha inválida" not valid

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment-timezone and I am trying to format the date
like this:

```
moment('dic. 23 2020  11:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

I am getting that it's not valid?

any idea why?

Comment: Is the use of  "dic." instead of "dec." comes from the locale you use? How do you get the date in this format?

Comment: yes it comes from local i use 
require('moment/locale/es');
moment.tz.setDefault('es');

I format the date that comes from a date piker. 
moment("2020-12-19T14:45:00.000Z").format('MMM DD YYYY  HH:mm'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the format parameter, after specifying the locale info. Have a look at this

```
const moment = require("moment");
require("moment/min/locales.min");
moment.locale("es");
const result = moment("dic. 23 2020  11:00", "MMM[.] DD YYYY hh:mm").format("YYYYMM-DD HH:mm");
console.log(result);
```